# Is $\sum 1/n$ finite for $n$ in a set $S$ of pos. integers satisfying $a<b$ with $a,b \in S$ & $a+b$ in $S$ —> $a+pb \notin S$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. Suppose $S$ is a set of positive integers with the property that for all elements $a,b \in S$, if $a < b$ and $a+b$ belongs to $S$, then $a+pb$ does not belong to S. Then is $\sum \frac{1}{n}$, where the summation is over all the elements $n$ of $S$, necessarily finite?

Comment: Why do you think this should hold? Have you tried to show this yourself? If so, could you add what you have done to the question?

Comment: Is $p$ any (positive) integer?

Comment: If p is odd I omitted the condition that S consists of even integers.

Answer (score 1):

The claim does not hold in general.

Define $S := \{ c + 2kp | k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ for some $c \in \mathbb{N}$ with $0 < c < p$.

Therefore $r_0 + r_1 \notin S$ for any arbitrarily chosen pair $(r_0, r_1) \in S^2 \text{ with } r_0 \neq r_1$.

Expanding the infinite sum:

$\quad \sum_{s \in S} ( \frac{1}{s} ) \\
> \; \sum_{s \in S \setminus \{c\}} ( \frac{1}{s} ) \\
= \; \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ( \frac{1}{c + 2kp} ) \\
> \; \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ( \frac{1}{2(k+1)p} ) \\
= \; \frac{1}{2p} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \\
= +\infty$